# How to use delegate as invoke parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, invoke

How do I give an action delegate as a parameter into invoke:

```
class C {
    static void A {}
    public static void F(Action action) { action(); }
}
```

Now I can call F directly:

```
F(A);
```

But how do I do the same with an invoke. The following does not compile:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(C).GetMethod("F", BindingFlags.Static |
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic);
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[]{ A });
```

Neither does anything else I have tried like:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[]{ C.A });
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[]{ () => C.A() });
```

The compiler says it cannot convert the parameter into "object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { new Action(C.A) });
```

Comment: Actually `new Action(C.A)`

Comment: @Alireza yes if it were in different class we need `C.A`. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you mark as answer, so that others will be benefited

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has a few problems:

1- Method `C.A` should be declared `public` in order to be used outside.

2- `BindingFlags.NonPublic` is preventing to access method `'F'` since it is `public`. Use `BindingFlags.Public` instead.

Now, you can do as:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { new Action(() => { C.A(); }) });
```

Comment: Your answer works too but Sriram's solution is more simple, the lambda is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, to update label1 in another thread, use the Invoke with arguments with a Lambda statement and the parameters the Func requires.

```
    Int32 c = 0;
    Int32 d = 0;
    Func<Int32, Int32,Int32> y;


    c = (Int32)(label1.Invoke(y = (x1, x2) => { label1.Text = (x1 +   
    x2).ToString();  return x1++; }, c,d));
    d++;
```

Generically, replace label1 by methodInfo. Use Func. With Action you can't pass arguments.